# How to audit SE elections results file on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, file-format

The [AskUbuntu 2016 Moderator Elections](https://askubuntu.com/election/5) have just finished (at the time of this writing), and this is what it says:

[image: How to audit election results]

However it only provides a utility to do this on Windows and Mac, how can one audit the results on Ubuntu (I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20)? The file type that the election data is stored in has the extension of `.blt`.

Comment: This should be linked on the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenSTV is in the Ubuntu repositories, all you need to do is install it with

```
sudo apt-get install openstv
```

You can run it on the election results file (the `.blt` file) you downloaded with

```
openstv-run-election MeekSTV askubuntu-com-2016-election-results.blt
```

Which will tell you exactly what it did.

If you want to know how it all works, there's a detailed summary here: [How are moderator election votes counted, in plain English?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english)

Answer (score 4):

Use `openstv` You can download it from the `universe` repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install openstv
```

And the result you can get like this:

```
wget -O ballot.blt http://askubuntu.com/election/download-result/5
openstv-run-election -r TextReport MeekSTV ballot.blt
```